# Load DMV with nested rowset column type into an SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular, dmv

I would like to load information from the DMV below into an SQL Server table:

```
select *
from $System.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS
```

This DMV returns a column named DIMENSION_PATH which type is *nested rowset* (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssas/fe23619e-3dd8-4599-be14-95ab2b327617).

Is there a way to transform this column to fit in an SQL Server table ?

I am using openqueries to access the system DMVs in SSAS.